# Union of queries depending on variable in list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a big Cypher query that is depending on a variable.

Example:

`With REGION = 'Canada'`

`query`

I want to execute this query several times based on different values on a list and return the UNION.

Something like:

`regions = ['Canada','Europe']`

`query_with_Canada UNION query_with_Europe`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking at is `UNWIND` :

```
UNWIND ['Canada','Europe'] AS location
<query with location>
RETURN value
```